# DNN Homepage goes straight to login page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm trying to solve a problem for a legacy client with DNN.  It seems when you go to their home page, you're redirected straight to a login page.  /login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f

- The admin settings show the correct page as the homepage.
- The permissions on that page is "All users"
- When you go to  **/Home.aspx**  instead of  **/**  the page loads normally.

I noticed "Splash Page" is not set. Could that help anything?

I know very little about DNN.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you happen to have a "redirect" option set in the Page settings?

What is the "Home" page in the site settings? Do you possibly have TWO home pages?

Comment: You were right about the 2 homepages.  Turns out the default page (which was not marked as the homepage in the site settings)  had its permissions denied, but was still enabled.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing from medium trust in the web.config to full trust?